# Disable Inarray Validator on Zend Form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a form that was working until I added two dropdown menus.  Since then, upon the submission of the form I get the error:

> haystack option is mandatory

This is my ProjectForm.php

```
<?php

namespace Project\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element\Text;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Form\Element\Select;
use Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox;
use Zend\Form\Element\Date;
use Zend\Config\Factory;
use Zend\Form\Element\Button;
use Zend\Form\Element\Textarea;
use Zend\Validator\Callback;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\Form\Element\File;

class ProjectForm extends Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface {

    const KEY_PROJECT_NAME = "project_name";
    const KEY_PROJECT_DUE_DTTM = "project_due_dttm";
    const KEY_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION = "project_description";
    const KEY_PROJECT_CONFIG = "project_config";
    const KEY_PROJECT_TYPES = "project_types"; 
    const KEY_PROJECT_WORKFLOW_CONFIG = "project_workflow_config";
    const KEY_PROJECT_WORKFLOW_TYPES = "project_workflow_types";
    const KEY_PROJECT_FILE = "project_file";
    const KEY_SAVE_BTN = "project_save_btn";
    const KEY_CANCEL_BTN = "project_cancel_btn";


    public function __construct($name = null, $options = array()) {
        parent::__construct($name);

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal');

        $name = new Text(self::KEY_PROJECT_NAME);
        $name->setAttribute("id", self::KEY_PROJECT_NAME);
        $name->setLabel("Name");

        $duedttm = new Text(self::KEY_PROJECT_DUE_DTTM);
        $duedttm->setAttribute("id", self::KEY_PROJECT_DUE_DTTM);
        $duedttm->setLabel("Due Date");

        $description = new Textarea(self::KEY_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION);
        $description->setAttribute("id", self::KEY_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION);
        $description->setLabel("Description");

        $config = new Textarea(self::KEY_PROJECT_CONFIG);
        $config->setAttribute("id", self::KEY_PROJECT_CONFIG);
        $config->setLabel("Configuration");

        $projectTypeDropDown = new Select(self::KEY_PROJECT_TYPES); 
        $projectTypeDropDown->setLabel('Project Type:'); 
        $projectTypeDropDown->setValueOptions($options["project"]); 

        $wfConfig = new Textarea(self::KEY_PROJECT_WORKFLOW_CONFIG);
        $wfConfig->setAttribute("id", self::KEY_PROJECT_WORKFLOW_CONFIG);
        $wfConfig->setLabel("Workflow Configuration");

        $projectWorkflowDropDown = new Select(self::KEY_PROJECT_WORKFLOW_TYPES);
        $projectWorkflowDropDown->setLabel('Workflow Type:');
        $projectWorkflowDropDown->setValueOptions(array());

        $file = new File(self::KEY_PROJECT_FILE);
        $file->setAttribute("id", self::KEY_PROJECT_FILE);
        $file->setAttribute("multiple", true);
        $file->setLabel("File");

        $save = new Button(self::KEY_SAVE_BTN);
        $save->setAttributes(array("id", self::KEY_SAVE_BTN));
        $save->setLabel("Save");
        $save->setValue("Save");

        $cancel = new Button(self::KEY_CANCEL_BTN);
        $cancel->setAttributes(array("id", self::KEY_CANCEL_BTN));
        $cancel->setLabel("Cancel");

        $this->add($name);
        $this->add($duedttm);
        $this->add($description);
        $this->add($config);
        $this->add($projectTypeDropDown); 
        $this->add($wfConfig);
        $this->add($projectWorkflowDropDown); 
        $this->add($file);
        $this->add($save);
        $this->add($cancel);
    }

    public function isValidJSON($value, $options) {
        try {
            JSON::decode($value);
            return true;
        } catch (JSONException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function isValidDateTime($value, $options) {
        if (false === date_create($value)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface::getInputFilterSpecification()
     */
    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array(
                ProjectForm::KEY_PROJECT_CONFIG => array(
                        'required' => true,
                        'filters' => array(
                                array(
                                        'name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim'
                                ),
                        ),
                        'validators' => array(
                                new Callback(
                                        array(
                                                $this,
                                                'isValidJSON'
                                        )),
                        ),
                ),
                ProjectForm::KEY_PROJECT_WORKFLOW_CONFIG => array(
                        'required' => false,
                        'filters' => array(
                                array(
                                        'name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim'
                                ),
                        ),
                        'validators' => array(
                                new Callback(
                                        array(
                                                $this,
                                                'isValidJSON'
                                        )),
                        ),
                ),
                ProjectForm::KEY_PROJECT_DUE_DTTM => array(
                        'required' => false,
                        'filters' => array(
                                array(
                                        'name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim'
                                ),
                        ),
                        'validators' => array(
                                new Callback(
                                        array(
                                                $this,
                                                'isValidDateTime'
                                        )),
                        ),
                ),

        );
    }
}
```

I think I need to disable the `inarray_validator` by adding `disable_inarray_validator' => true` but I'm not sure where to add this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the version of Zend that I am using, I had to add this to the controller before validating the form:

```
// Make certain to merge the files info!
$post = array_merge_recursive($request->getPost()->toArray(), $request->getFiles()->toArray());

//Deals with validation of dynamic form 
$projectType = $projectTypes[$post["project_types"]]; 
$form->get('project_workflow_types')->setValueOptions($workflowTypes[$projectType]); 


// set the form instance's data
$form->setData($post);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you pass an empty string as a unique valueOption. In your javascript you flush the `<option>` tags of the select to get rid of this empty option.
Also you will have to disable the default validator of the Select element by adding :

```
$projectWorkflowDropDown->setOptions(array('disable_inarray_validator' => true));
```

Or

```
$projectWorkflowDropDown->setDisableInArrayValidator(true);
```

If you don't add this option, when the form will be submitted, Zend Form will tell you the value send is not in the haystack provided when the form was built. This is a safety process which is very helpful in many cases, just not in your.

Comment: After trying the second option I get `Call to undefined method Zend\Form\Element\Select::setDisableInArrayValidator()`.  Am I missing something that needs to be included?

Comment: What is your version of Zend ? This is strange, http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.4/classes/Zend.Form.Element.Select.html#method_setDisableInArrayValidator says the method is public. Have you tried the option instead ?

Comment: I'm using Zend version 2.1.0.  And I tried the other option but I get the same haystack error

Comment: You have to use an empty string as single value in your dropdown + the option.
$projectWorkflowDropDown->setValueOptions(array(''));